# Reading Text Files Java:15 Error: Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, class, file-io, text-files, command-prompt

Im trying to read the content from a text file. ReadTextFile.java and ReadTextFileTest.java are in the same package ReadTextFile. I am using 2 packages in one project, ReadTextFiles and CreateTextfiles. ReadTextFiles package reads content from a text file and CreateTextFile package inputs content into a text file.

When I get to the command prompt I try to compile the java file into a class file by javac ReadTextFileTest.java. I get the following error everytime.

1. ReadTextFileTest.java:15 error: cannot find symbol
2. ReadTextFile application = new ReadTextFile();
3. ^
4. symbol:   class ReadTextFile
5. location: class ReadTextFileTest
6. ReadTextFileTest.java:15 error: cannot find symbol
7. ReadTextFile application = new ReadTextFile();
8. ^
9. symbol:   class ReadTextFile
10. location: class ReadTextFileTest
    11.2 errors

Im guessing its having trouble recognizing the object I created of the ReadTextFile.java class.

Here is the two classes I used:
ReadTextFile.java

```
package ReadTextFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import AccountRecord.AccountRecord; 




public class ReadTextFile
{
    private Scanner input;

public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        input = new Scanner( new File( "clients.txt" ) );
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException )
    {
        System.err.println( "Error opening file." );
        System.exit(1);
    }    
}

public void readRecords()
{
    AccountRecord record = new AccountRecord();

    System.out.printf( "%-10s%-12s%-12s%10s\n", "Account",
            "First Name", "Last Name", "Balance" );

    try
    {
        while ( input.hasNext() )
        {
            record.setAccount( input.nextInt() );
            record.setFirstName( input.next() );
            record.setLastName( input.next() );
            record.setBalance( input.nextDouble() );

            System.out.printf( "%-10d%-12s%-12s%10.2f\n",
                    record.getAccount(), record.getFirstName(),
                    record.getLastName(), record.getBalance() );
        }    
    }
    catch ( NoSuchElementException elementException )
    {
        System.err.println( "File improperly formed." );
        input.close();
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
    catch ( IlegalStateException stateException )
    {
        System.err.println( "Error opening file." );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }    
}

public void closeFile()
{
    if ( input !=null )
        input.close();
}        
}
```

ReadTextFileTest.java

```
package ReadTextFile;

public class ReadTextFileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ReadTextFile application = new ReadTextFile();

    application.openFile();
    application.readRecords();
    application.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `ReadTextFileTest.java` and `ReadTextFile.java` located at same package?

Comment: Check if both the files are in same package, or proper import statement is added. You can add import statement as below:-

Comment: Yes they are in a package called ReadTextFile..

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
package ReadTextFile;
```

`ReadTextFile` is not a package but a class. Remove this line and try to compile again.

You must have meant

```
import readTextFile;
```

but if you make sure it is in the same directory, you don't have to import it. So, just delete the first line of `ReadTextFileTest`.

### Edit after comment:

Generally, avoid naming packages with the same names as classes ( although as @Masud said in the comments it is possible). You should follow [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) naming conventions.

Comment: class name and package name can be same.

Comment: You are right. I just assumed that @user3051122 (maybe wrongly) has confused `import` with `package` due to the nature of the Error.

Comment: Even though ReadTextFile.java and ReadTextFileTest.java is in the same package ReadTextFile?

Comment: Yes I have that a the top on the first line.

Comment: What is the name  of the directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add import statement as below:-

package ReadTextFile;

import ReadTextFile;

public class ReadTextFileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ReadTextFile application = new ReadTextFile();

    application.openFile();
    application.readRecords();
    application.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: It says I dont have to ReadTextFile them because there in the same package.

Comment: then remove both these lines:-package ReadTextFile;